# iphone : objective-c : how to compress NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to compress an NSString. How I can do that in objective-c (iphone).

Comment: What do you mean by «compressing»? Give us some more details if you want an answer...

Comment: How much text in the string? Some compression algorithms will make the  string bigger.  If it is very short text under 300 there are some short string compression algorithms that can be used to make it smaller.

Comment: @John Ballinger - in fact all compression algorithms will make some strings longer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015904/compress-decompress-nsstring-in-objective-c-iphone-using-gzip-or-deflate) you may find you answer.