# unzip SOAP message with xcode

Tags: iphone, soap, xcode4, compression

In order to improve the client/server behaviour, I'm looking for adapt my iphone client code to proceed ziped responses.

The server adapt the SOAP response ziped.

I was looking how to uncompress the response but didn't work for me.

The first solution I studied was the [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/detail?name=ZipArchive.zip&can=2&q=), explained [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7615-simple-objective-c-class-zip-unzip-zip-format-files.html), solution (from minizip) but it is focus on filesystem compression.

And I just need to uncompress a NSString.

After that I checked this [second approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015904/compress-decompress-nsstring-in-objective-c-iphone-using-gzip-or-deflate):

```
NSData *decodedGzippedData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:encodedGzippedString];
NSData* unGzippedJsonData = [ASIHTTPRequest uncompressZippedData:decodedGzippedData];   
NSString* unGzippedJsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unGzippedJsonData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

But didn't work for me, because in the actual version the NSData dataFromBase64String didn't exists.

Now I'm working with the third response of the previous question, anybody knows which library or framework I need to install in order to import Base64.h and NSData+Compression.h ¿? Used in this other potencial [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015904/compress-decompress-nsstring-in-objective-c-iphone-using-gzip-or-deflate/3839719#3839719)

Comment: I was testing the chilkat library with the same result ... :((( http://www.example-code.com/ios/zip.asp. 

The solution is only applied to filesystem :SSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the next.

Install the next libraries to your project:

- Base64.h // You can find it [here](http://www.cocoabob.net/?p=7)
- NSData+Compression.h // You can find it [here](https://github.com/geoffgarside/cocoagit/tree/master/Source)

Use the code of one of the [previous solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015904/compress-decompress-nsstring-in-objective-c-iphone-using-gzip-or-deflate)

```
#import "Base64.h"
#import "NSData+compression.h"

...

// decoding the base64 ziped message
Byte inputData[[stringValue lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[stringValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] getBytes:inputData];
size_t inputDataSize = (size_t)[stringValue length];
size_t outputDataSize = EstimateBas64DecodedDataSize(inputDataSize);
Byte outputData[outputDataSize];//prepare a Byte[] for the decoded data
Base64DecodeData(inputData, inputDataSize, outputData, &outputDataSize);

// inflate the original string using gzip
NSData *theData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:outputData length:outputDataSize];
NSData* result = [theData gzipInflate];//make bigger==gunzip

// Return the result
return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```