# Compressing NSString in Objective c and decompressing it on Java Server

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, web-services, compression

I am calling Java Web service in iOS app by making NSURLRequest by posting web service URL.
I am successfully able to get response data from NSURLResponse.

But my problem here is I have to send few parameters in in web service URl as query string, I want to compress this parameter which is NSString in objective C and retrieve it on server side and decompress it.

So I just want to know here is there any way I can compress NSString at iOS client layer and decompress it at Java web service level for further processing.

Comment: Why do you want to compress, is the string huge ?

Comment: Found answer to my own question as I was referring to below two links...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015904/compress-decompress-nsstring-in-objective-c-iphone-using-gzip-or-deflate?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

https://gist.github.com/yfnick/227e0c12957a329ad138